# Salesforce (as IdP) returns error response to every SAML Single Logout request

Tags: api, single-sign-on, connected-apps, saml, identity

I'm having trouble getting Salesforce SAML single logout (SLO) working. I'm writing a web application that uses Salesforce as the SAML Identitiy Provider (IdP)

Every `LogoutRequest` I send gets a response with a `StatusCode` of "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder", which according to the spec means that an error has occurred in Salesforce.

However, I can't find any other details about what might be wrong. There isn't anything in the "Identity Provider Event Log", and no other details in the `LogoutResponse`. Does anyone know how to debug this issue, or what might be wrong? I've included an example `LogoutRequest` and the `LogoutResponse` below:

Request:

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest
        Destination="https://example.cs13.my.salesforce.com/services/auth/idp/saml2/logout"
        ID="EXAMPLE_ID"
        IssueInstant="2018-05-03T18:18:32Z"
        Version="2.0"
        xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
        xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer>
        http://subdomain.example.com
    </saml:Issuer>
    <saml:NameID>
        username@example.com
    </saml:NameID>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:LogoutResponse xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                      Destination="https://localhost/logout/callback"
                      ID="EXAMPLE_ID_2"
                      InResponseTo="EXAMPLE_ID"
                      IssueInstant="2018-05-03T13:59:57.627Z" Version="2.0">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        https://example.cs13.my.salesforce.com
    </saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder"/>
    </samlp:Status>
</samlp:LogoutResponse>
```

And here is a screen shot of my connected app settings:
[image]

Comment: Do we have a fix for this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I never found one. I worked around it by loading the community logout page in an iframe when I wanted the user to be logged out. e.g. `<iframe src="{{YOUR COMMUNITY URL}}/secur/logout.jsp" style="width:0; height:0; border:0; border:none;"></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to set the NameID and SessionIndex Attribute from the SSO Login Assertion in the Logout Request as well. I can see from your Logout Request that you are not doing this, so you get the status:Responder which is a slight hint that something went wrong. If you miss those values Salesforce will not know which Session to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

According our development with Salesforce SAML SSO integration, we found each Single Sign On operation can only successfully logout once, and then will returns "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder".
I believe the Salesforce has some verification logic during the SAML Single Logout processing, it might requires an available session with correct matched NameID or something.
However, I cannot find out any related settings in Salesforce to turn it off or make it works as we expected, this needs someone inside to answer the root reason.